# possible for Socket IO client application to communicate with Winsock server application?

Tags: javascript, html, c++, socket.io, winsock

i would like to know if it is possible to have socket.io featured client website to send message to winsock c++ server application?

My current project involve controlling a robot using c++ application and i have design a simple local host website.

i would like to have a web page as user interface (client) and my c++ application (server) that will accept connection from client and listen to the port for incoming messages. ( which mean socket.io interacting with winsock through IP)

I have a working C++ winsock client/server application that are able to communicate between each other using winsock. Besides that, i have play around with the socket.io demo chat from this webpage http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

If so, is there any good tutorial or guideline out there that capable of having the sockets interaction? i have no luck finding one.

Thanks

Comment: Are you making your project for Wifibot? :) I came across the same problem